# How do I wrap Ajax rights checks in a function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have a rights check via Ajax:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
 url: [url_php],
 params: {
  ssid: Ext.util.Cookies.get("token"),
  access_id: 1000000057
 },
success: function(response, opts){
  res = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
  if (res.success == true) {
   Ext.getCmp('CardUser').setHidden(false);
  }
 },
});
```

It turns out that there will be a lot of them. can this be output to a separate function, for example, for compactness of the code?

Comment: You can override the component and add appropriate feature there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can override the Ext.Component to add permissions mechanism there. It will be something like this:

```
Ext.define('overrides.Component', {
    override: 'Ext.Component',

    accessId: false,
    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent();
        if (this.accessId) {
            this.checkPermissions()
        }
    },

    checkPermissions() {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'checkPermissions.json',
            params: {
                ssid: Ext.util.Cookies.get("token"),
                access_id: this.accessId
            },
            success: function (response, opts) {
                res = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                this.setHidden(res.success === true);
            },
            scope: this
        });
    }
});
```

The 'Ext.Component' is the base class of all the Ext elements (text field, form, grid.. toolbar). So all the child components will get this feature.

In the following fiddle example the gui sub-elements make ajax requests and hide themself if they become success: false (that is random). Just make re-run of the application to see the result.

[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/37ci)

Of course you must edit this solution to your needs.

**Disadvantages of this solution:**

- You will make a lot of ajax requests which is not good, better to
  implement some batch mode mechanism.
- if the component is hidden by default settings it will be shown, so you need to implement also this logic.
  ...
  ...

Comment: You need to put the accessId in the tabConfig property. Have a look at the fiddle example again, I have added hide(a)ble tabs there.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot!

Comment: I decided to rewrite the code a bit to avoid a large number of AJAX requests. I decided to read access_id when logging in to the app. 

Here I put an array of allowed access rights access_id in a variable:
**LoginController.js:**

`App.Global.setAccess(res.access)`

Here I try to count, but for some reason the variable is empty:
**app.js**
`checkPermissions() {var access = App.Global.getAccess(); this.setHidden(access.includes(this.accessId) === false); }`